# fopen() can't write with error "HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections"

Tags: php

I have a file with url: `http://localhost:8080/cache/a66b311547bf3da88f01139271d5bb50.txt`
And in php I using code:

```
$file = "http://localhost:8080/cache/a66b311547bf3da88f01139271d5bb50.txt"
$output = serialize($data);
$fp = fopen($file, "w");
fputs($fp, $output);
fclose($fp);
```

When run code, is error

> Warning: fopen(http://localhost:8080/cache/a66b311547bf3da88f01139271d5bb50.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections ...

How to fix it?

Comment: As the error message is telling you, it cannot be "fixed".

Comment: really? is there no other solution to fix this kind of issue!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write using http, you have to use the local file system to write files.

e.g. see http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/file_write_php.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cache/a66b311547bf3da88f01139271d5bb50.txt";
$output = serialize($data);
file_put_contents($file,$output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to write something to an online file.

What you could do is download the file, and write something to it.

Answer (score 0):

fopen() allows read-only access to files/resources via HTTP 1.0, using the HTTP GET method.
You should not use the mode 'w'

```
$fp = fopen($file, "w");
```

Please change to 'r'

```
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
```

Comment: Chnange the fopen mode to read. Not Write, Because write is not permit for the http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your webmin and give that folder to write **permission** and in your code set **absolute path** like this.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){//for live server
   $file = fopen('/var/www/html/etijarat.pk/feed/file.csv', 'w');
}else{// for your local
    $file = fopen('./feed/file.csv', 'w');
}
```